# can't disable xpack security for kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We set up a elasticsearch cluster, installed Kibana and x-pack. Now the Kibana login screen display error message:

Login is disabled because your license has expired. Please extend your license or disable Security in Elasticsearch.

On line document suggested to put

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

in both es and kibana configuration files. Made the change, restarted both services and still get the error message.

Tried to remove x-pack but got this error message:

```
# bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove x-pack
/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch: line 67: xpack.security.enabled:: command not found
Unable to source environment file: /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
```

Have to change the ':' to '=' to complete the remove process. Seems no way to use x-pack without license.

Comment: Have you tried a basic license, to avoid removing x-pack?https://register.elastic.co

Comment: I don't know that @Imma Thanks for the link.

Comment: Just a note here, the above only applies to version 6.2 and below.